# InteractionRequiredAuthError: invalid_grant: AADSTS50076

Tags: azure-active-directory, msal-react

**Error message:** Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access 'bxxx-xxxx-xxxxa'.

I am getting this error intermittently, while accessing token with auth code.
Token endpoint fails with error code 400.
Request body in browser contains:

POST: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

1. clientId,
2. scope - xxxxxxxx/.default openid profile offline_access
3. grant_type: authorization_code
4. code
5. redirect_uri

and here is MSAL configuration: (we are using react-msal 1.4.3)

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: env?.ClientId,
    authority: env?.Authority,
    redirectUri: env?.RedirectUri,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: env?.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
  scopes: [env?.AuthScope],
}
```

Please let me know if anyone has encounter this issue before and found any solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

•   It is because your administrator has **`enabled the security defaults setting in ‘Manage security defaults’ section in Azure AD tenant properties`** as shown below in the snapshot. When you enable this option, **Azure AD mandates all users to register for Azure AD multi-factor authentication, requires the same for administrators and enforces it, blocks legacy authentication protocols, and protects privileged activities like access to the Azure portal**.

[image: Azure AD properties]

Thus, if **you are assigned a role of ‘Administrator’ of any sort, i.e., Global, Authentication, Application, Billing, Exchange, etc., then your ID would be required to do multi-factor authentication**. Also, please **ensure that you are not using any older protocol and legacy authentication since those doesn’t have access to multi-factor authentication**.

As a result, this would help in resolving the issue and the subsequent error that you are facing. For more information, kindly refer to the below links given: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults***

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/494959/aadsts50076-ue-to-a-configuration-change-made-by-y.html***

Comment: Deeply appreciated, 3 days looking for this issue solution

Comment: CAn you help with: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75274922/2441637

Comment: Crazy thing is, I have a 2fa configured, but when I try to log into Azure portal, it never asks me to use it. 

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this in case someone else has the same issue.

I got this error but it was actually due to that fact that when I rotated the client secret, I mistakingly put the new client secret in the client id field.

The error obviously didn't explain it didn't recognise the client id and given I had just used a VPN it threw me off for a while until I spotted my mistake!!