# User unauthorized though the token is correct

Tags: azure, odata, dynamics-365-operations, dynamics-ax7

I'm trying to integrate D365FO with a third party application, I was able to do the proper setup and register my app, fetch the Token as shown below:

[image]

I used the `resource` as the link for D365FO at the development machine, which is `https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com/` and read the D365FO data as shown below:

[image]

I want to change the login method, so I do login on behalf of the user, using the password, so I Disabled the security details at Azure (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73402697/2441637)), as below:

[image]

And got the token of the logged user successful as below:

[image]

[image]

But once I tried fetching the same data which I was able to fetch before, I got 401 unauthorized, though I'm logging in using the `Admin` account:

[image]

Comment: Have to do some research on this. If you have access, check https://www.yammer.com/dynamicsaxfeedbackprograms/threads/1977086491377664 where something similar along these lines is described.

Comment: @Hasan A Yousef, could you include the value of the **resource** parameter in the first request and your app's `API permissions` snapshot too?

Comment: @Sridevi the `resource` used is the default link for D365FO at the development machine, which is `https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error **`401 Unauthorized`** usually occurs if you make calls to the resource with **invalid** audience.

When you generate the access token with `scope` as *user.read openid profile offline_access*, audience will be **Microsoft Graph** that won't work with D365FO.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** like below:

[image]

Now I generated tokens with grant type as `password` by including **same** parameters as you like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: user.read openid profile offline_access
grant_type: password
username: admin@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) to check the audience.

When I decoded the access token, I got **aud** claim as  `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` (i.e, Microsoft Graph) like below:

[image]

If you use this token to read D365FO data, you will get **401 Unauthorized** error as audience is invalid.

To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token with `resource` value as **base URL** of your D365FO instance by making below changes:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
resource: <base URL of your D365FO instance without the trailing '/'>
grant_type: password
username: admin@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxxxxxx
```

In your case, value of **resource** parameter should be `https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com`

This token will have **audience** same as your  D365FO root URL. To confirm that, you can decode it in  [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/). If you use this token to read  D365FO data, it will work!

**Reference:**

[Test services by using third-party utilities - Finance & Operations | Dynamics 365 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/third-party-service-test#prerequisites)

Comment: Thanks a lot, is the `client_secret` required, as I was to get the token without it!

Comment: The `client_secret` is **not** required if you enabled the [Allow public client flows](https://i.imgur.com/GIzcmHt.png) option.

Comment: Thanks, I switched off and it required the client_secret, deeply appreciate your support.